# Gmail Inline images converted to attachments

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, webmail

Since the beginning of October 2023 gmail webmail has started having this issue: when you receive a forwarded mail with inline images you just see a white box, the images are present only as attachment. This is quite annoying!

[Here is a technical explanation](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Workspace-Q-A/Inline-images-getting-silently-converted-to-attachments-AFTER/m-p/636996#M14501), but I couldn't find a solution yet.
I think many people are frustrated about this bug and are looking for posts about that; but it's hard to find them searching with google at the moment, I found only the one above, the others are old and not relevant.
I hope my question will help someone, thank you for comments

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been fixed by Google as reported [here](https://The%20issue%20has%20been%20fixed%20by%20Google%20as%20reported%20here:%20https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Workspace-Q-A/Inline-images-getting-silently-converted-to-attachments-AFTER/m-p/649121#M15007)